# Erro na assinatura do XML do NFs-e Belo Horizonte

Tags: c#, xml, web-service, nfe

Estou desenvolvendo a integração de um sistema para emissão de Nfse para Belo Horizonte estão acontecendo 2 situações que apenas com essa prefeitura que desenvolvi estão acontecendo, já temos integrados várias prefeituras e essa é a que está dando mais trabalho.(Pelo menos até agora)

1) Pelo manual do ABRASF a tag Signature da RPS não é obrigatório, pelo menos é o que eu entendi no manual aonde indica:

TcRPS|  Signature| Tipo | dsig:Signature | Ocorrência 0- 1.

página 27 do manual de integração de BH - [Link manual de BH](http://www.pbh.gov.br/bhissdigital/download/nfse/Manual_De_Integracao_WebService_NFS-e_Belo_Horizonte.pdf) , se eu não assinar a RPS, a seguinte mensagem é retornada pelo web service de teste de BH:

```
<Codigo>E176</Codigo>

<Mensagem>Rps sem assinatura.</Mensagem>
```

Se eu assinar a RPS e tentar a emissão, ele de cara me retorna "XML com erro na assinatura", mas não entendo  o porque, da mesma forma que assinei o Lote, estou assinando a RPS, e da mesma forma assinamos as outras prefeituras que temos homologado.
O arquivo XML está igual ao que é disponibilizado no portal da prefeitura de BH.

Retorno de quando a *tag* InfRPS é assinada:

```
<Codigo>E174</Codigo>
<Mensagem>Arquivo enviado com erro na assinatura.</Mensagem>
```

2) A outra situação que está acontecendo é, eu tenho duas RPSs na fila, faço o envio de uma ok me retorna algum desses erros ou se a RPS foi convertida em Nfse, quando vou fazer o segundo envio da outra RPS, acontece uma exception: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel, mas o estranho é que se parar a depuração e reiniciar após algum tempo, eu consigo me fazer a chamada para o ws novamente.

Comment: Estou enfrentando o mesmo problema. Você conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aproveitarei para deixar a solução encontrada para o problema e já respondendo ao Oeslei.

O problema na assinatura do XML foi solucionado colocando o atributo 
"xmlns" com o valor "http://www.abrasf.org.br/nfse.xsd" nas tags LoteRps, Rps e InfRps.

O 2º problema da mensagem de erro "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" que ocorria quando eu tentava realizar mais de uma requisição para o webservice.
Resolvi mudando a forma de como o sistema se comunicava com o webservice, inicialmente adicionávamos o endereço do webservice através do WebReference e utilizávamos essa classe para se comunicar com o webservice.
Agora realizando a comunicação através da classe HttpWebRequest o problema não se repetiu, e consigo realizar várias requisições para o webservice de BH, o estranho é que para outros webservices de outras prefeituras não precisamos utilizar o HttpWebRequest.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: estou enfrentando o mesmo problema, porém ainda não consegui resolver. Gostaria de saber se é necessário adicionar algum namespace na tag `SignedInfo` para gerar a chave de `SignatureValue`. Estou a 2 semanas tentando assinar um RPS e nada.